# LinearLayout and RecyclerView won't scroll together

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I've surfed lots of posts but couldn't get the one I needed. I have a LinearLayout with a RecyclerView, and I want both to scroll. Now, the LinearLayout is fixed and the RecyclerView is the only one that scrolls. I tried with nestedscrollview but couldn't make it work. For some reason the recyclerview.adapter breaks using nestedscrollview. Any idea? 
btw: I'm developing in Xamarin Android

This is my Layout

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
         ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I load a fragment in the framelayout which layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinearLayouts by themselves don't scroll, they're just for easily organizing one view after another after another in a linear fashion. If you want to get one to scroll you'd need to nest it inside of a ScrollView.

Given what you're trying to accomplish, though, I don't know that nesting a RecyclerView inside of a ScrollView is going to work. (I haven't confirmed this)

What's the behavior you're looking for with the LinearLayout? Is it supposed contain headers and footers? If so, you may be better served by creating unique ViewHolders for your RecyclerView (i.e. one for your header, one for your footer, and a third for your regular content). Then your adapter figures out which type of ViewHolder to display based on its index. (e.g. 0 -> Header, n+2 -> Footer, 1:n-1 -> Content (offset by 1))

If you're just looking for a static header (i.e. one that doesn't scroll with the rest of the content, you can achieve that pretty easily:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <!-- Replace this with your header view -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Your Header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you a header view that will take up 1/5th of the total height of the containing view. The RecyclerView (including its containing view and the progress bar) are in a view that will encompass the remaining 4/5ths of the total height of the containing view.

Comment: It's a header, but considering my solution, it's not the best idea to make a Header Viewholder for the recyclerview. I used the LinearLayout to organize the views. Semantically is a header. Do you recommend changing LinearLayout to another layout?

Comment: It depends. When you scroll, do you want the header to disappear? Or do you want it to always be present? Do you want the footer to only appear when you've scrolled to the bottom? You could keep the LinearLayout *without* a ScrollView, insert the header there, and only have the second element be the RecyclerView (which will scroll on its own).

Why is defining Header ViewHolders not an ideal solution for you?

Comment: Suppose I want it to be like a first item. I don't want it to disappear, just to be at the top. Defining a Header ViewHolders is not ideal because the recyclerview is a component I use in another views, and in the others I don't want the header. It's complicated if you don't know the solution, but trust me, it's better to do it separated. I don't have footer, only header. I don't understand the solution you are giving me, do you have an example/tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: @FedeBerco I've added an example of a header which doesn't move, using `weightSum` and `layout_weight` to achieve a 1:4 fill for the header/content. You can play around with the values to get it to look how you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to scroll the content of your RecyclerView and the surrounding Views that are also placed inside the LinearLayout as if they were inside just one scroll container.

To solve this problem you can use a NestedScrollLayout.
So that your layout would look similar to this:

```
<NestedScrollLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</NestedScrollLayout>
```

Now you can achieve your goal through inserting one additional line into your code:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listRecyclerView, false);
```

This line has to be added to after you attach your RecyclerViewAdapter to your RecyclerView.
After the scrolling behaviour should be just like you wanted it to.

You might reread this solution here: https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/05/recyclerview-scrolling-issue-with-nestedscrollview/

I adopted his way to your problem, as the author describes his method a bit more generalised.

I hope this will be helpful to you and others that cross this problem.

Edit: Unfortunately this method has two downsides i just came across.

First it disables the scrolling of the RecyclerView and as a consequence any ScrollListener that is set onto the RecyclerView will not trigger anymore.

Secondly when you put `setNestedScrollingEnabled` to `false` the benefits of a RecyclerView are not present anymore. Your RecyclerView cannot make use of the recycling feature in this setting. That means, that all items inside your list will be rendered directly at the beginning. This might be cause your app to perform bad if you have lots of items inside your list, because it will need longer to lay everything out and it needs much more memory.